# stickyHeader covers up target row of hash link

Tags: tablesorter

I'm having trouble with stickyHeaders widget on tablesorter covering the first row of a table when the URL includes a hash.

For example living.php?tab=1#sacramento1

The page displays the correct tab and jumps to the correct row, but the header is displayed over the row.

In order to get around this, I've been disabling the stickyHeader widget if there is a hash in the url

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
  //CHECK for hash. don't want sticky headers with hash
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var workingID = window.location.hash;
    tid=workingID.substr(1,workingID.length);
    document.getElementById(tid).setAttribute("class", "showRow");
    // extend the default setting to always include the zebra widget. 
    $.tablesorter.defaults.widgets = ['zebra'];
  } else {
    // extend the default setting to always include the zebra widget and the sticky headers. 
    $.tablesorter.defaults.widgets = ['zebra','stickyHeaders'];
  }
  // extend the default setting to always sort on the first column 
    $.tablesorter.defaults.sortList = [[0,0]]; 
    // call the tablesorter plugin 
    $("table").tablesorter();   
}
```

);

Is there a way to get stickyHeaders to recognize the hash row and display it below the header?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/149/)):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        window.location.hash = this.hash;
        // find table that link is inside
        var $table = $(this).closest('table'),
            // get stickheader height + a little extra,
            // if the link is in a table & table has a stickyheader...
            shHeight = ( $table.find('.tablesorter-stickyHeader').parent().height() || 0 ) * 1.2;
        // move the anchor below the sticky header
        $(window).scrollTop( $(window).scrollTop() - shHeight);
        // prevent anchor from controlling the scrollTop
        return false;
    }
});
```

​